# Learning reason of incorrect redirect in Nginx

Tags: nginx, web-server, redirect

There's a web app url of which may vary - it's either *.com or my.*.com depending on if a user is logged or not.

However, there's an element on the main page (that can be accessed via *.com or my.*.com) that requires authentication.

If the logged user accesses the my.*.com and clicks a button it works with no issue. There's just 1 POST request returning 200 as expected.

[200](https://i.stack.imgur.com/npAMM.png)

However, if the logged user access the *.com and clicks the button it results in 2 unsuccessful POST requests. One goes to *.com returning 307. The other one goes to my.*.com and returns 403.

[307](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebeHi.png)

[403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YW67O.png)

I believe that the problem has to do with misconfigured nginx. My hypothesis is that when the user is redirected no credentials are passed to the backend, that's why I get 403.

Is there something else that might cause the problem?
I don't have the full nginx config file but at first sight there's only this redirect used for ssl or should I keep looking futher? :

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  my.ft01.com;
    server_tokens off;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    return       301 https://my.ft01.com$request_uri; 
}
```